# Running netflix on chrome gives "browser not supported" Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, streaming, netflix

I've been using Netflix on Chrome, Ubuntu 18.04, fine for months now.

Today i got the error message:
  M7121-3078
  Browser not supported

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the version of google chrome You are using ? `It means that the version of Google Chrome currently installed on your computer is no longer supported.`. Update google chrome to latest version.

Comment: It was ver 69. I upgraded to 78, whereupon Netflix started to work, but most other things didn't. Askubuntu worked as far as entering this comment! However, as of this moment, things have started to work again. So we'll see whether I have to uninstall and reinstall...